# Spark-submit python job: error 'No module named 'subpackage' '

Tags: python, pyspark

I am having troubles running a spark job because each worker does not seem to locate my project package. For each worker, I am getting the error `No module named 'subpackage'`

I have got the following project structure:

```
.
├── myproject
    ├── mainpackage
        ├── subpackage
            ├── __init__.py
            └── moduleA    
        ├── __init__.py
        └── __main__.py
    └── dist
        └── myproject-1.0.egg
├── README
├── setup.py
└── ...
```

The main logic is obviously contained within the `__main__.py`. All this project structure was packed into the `myproject-1.0.egg` egg file.

I want to submit this module as a spark job. To do so, I trigger the following command:

```
$ spark-submit \
--num-executors 10 \
--executor-cores 4 \
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python \
--py-files /absolutepath/myproject/dist/myproject-1.0.egg \
mainpackage/__main__.py \
```

The most relevant part of my `__main.py__.py` is:

```python
from subpackage.moduleA import ClassA
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SQLContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    sc.addPyFile('dist/myproject-1.0.egg')
    spark = SQLContext(sc)
    ...
```

I may provide further information or code if it proves not to be enough. I am open to code & project structure improvements as well.

Comment: There is no `__init__.py`  in the subpackage. If fixing that that doesn't resolve the problem please include `setup.py`.

Comment: There is, I just forgot to put it. Sorry. Updated